# Rotate multiple objects around mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, rotation, mouse

I'm trying to make multiple divs rotate around the mouse.

The issue i'm having is that all of the objects are following the rotation of the first one. I have no clue how i can make them rotate independently.

Is there a way to use the same code for all of the objects using the same class?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var player = $('.drop');
      //Checks to see which key is pressed down

      $(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {

        //Current position
        var p1 = {
          x: player.offset().left,
          y: player.offset().top
        };

        //Future position
        var p2 = {
          x: e.offsetX,
          y: e.offsetY
        };

        //Angle between them in degrees
        var angleDeg = (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;

        if(angleDeg >= 360){
          angleDeg -= 360;
        }

          //Animate the whole thing
          player.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angleDeg + 'deg)');
      });
  });
```

http://codepen.io/thalesribeiro/pen/egVgpp

Cheers,
Thales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to set up a `mousemove` event handler on the `document`, not the individual `div` elements, so that movement anywhere on the page triggers the divs to follow the mouse.

Also, to get each `div` to track the mouse with its own radius, all the `div` elements needed to be looped over so that a separate calculation for each could occur.

Because of the loop, a closure is set up and to avoid scope sharing that comes with closures, variable declarations were changed from `var` to `let`.

See the code for a comment on this.

```js
$(function(){
  
  var player = $('window');
  
  // Give the document a mousemove event handler
  $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    
    // If we are hovering over one of the div elements, exit the function
    if(e.target.nodeName === "DIV"){ return; }
        
    // Loop through each div and set its rotation separately from each other one  
    $(".drop").each(function(){
      
      // Declare all variables using "let" instead of "var" to avoid closure side-effects
      // of scope sharing
      
      //  Current position
      let p1 = {
            x: $(this).offset().left,
            y: $(this).offset().top
      };
      
      // Future position
      let p2 = {
            x: e.offsetX,
            y: e.offsetY
      };

      // Angle between them in degrees
      let angleDeg = (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;

      if(angleDeg >= 360){
        angleDeg -= 360;
      }

      // Just move the div that we're looping over at the moment
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angleDeg + 'deg)');
        
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body{ background:#ccc; }

.container { width:75%; margin:10% auto 0 auto; }

.drop{
  background:red;
  width:10px;
  height:50px;
  margin:35px;
  float:left;
}

.other { 
  background:blue;
  width:10px;
  height:50px;
  margin:25px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="drop"></div>
    
    <div class="other"></div>
    <div class="other"></div>
    
    
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping out. That's not quite there yet on what i'm trying to do. I want all the arrow to rotate independently following the mouse everywhere it goes. At the moment it's doing a weird behaviour that it only moves when i hover each arrow.

Comment: I think i might have to do something with array and .each but i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @ThalesRibeiro Take a look now. There were two issues. 1) you needed to set up a `mousemove` event handler for the `document`, not the `div` elements, so that  when you move anywhere in the document, the `div` elements will move relative to the mouse on the document and 2) You need to calculate the position of rotation for each div, so looping through them is necessary.

Comment: That's awesome Scott! It's working now. Just one question tho. When i add other elements to the composition, i get a glitch on the rotation. Is that normal ? http://codepen.io/thalesribeiro/pen/egVgpp If you hover the blue object you will see the glitch.

Comment: @ThalesRibeiro I added a single line of code that fixes that by checking to see if the element being moused over is a `div`. If so, exit the function.  Please up vote my answer and mark as "the" answer if this is doing what you were asking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had previously fixed this issue on a small scale, but when I added this to my actual project code, it conflicted. I created another version of it, but i'm again struggling to make the code smarter and it's getting a little bit slow in the browser, so i'm wondering if there's a way to make it lighter.

```
  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw) {
      var offset = pw.offset();
      var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
      var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
      var mouse_x = e.pageX;
      var mouse_y = e.pageY;
      var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
      var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1);
      $(pw).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
          rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD1'));
        });
        $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
          rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD2'));
        });
        $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
          rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD3'));
        });
        $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
          rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD4'));
        });
        $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
          rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD5'));
        });
        $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
          rotateOnMouse(e2, $('#arrowD6'));
        });
      });
```

http://codepen.io/thalesribeiro/pen/egVgpp